# Instability on Ubuntu 11.10 for wifi Intel Board 4965

Tags: wireless, intel

I'm a ubuntu user for a long time and always preferred to use LTS versions. But I decided to give a chance to 11.10 while 12.04 don't show up. But the wifi on 11.10 is not very stable which keeps me back on my 10.04 installation.
   Here is the deal i have the following card (lspci):

```
0c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection (rev 61)
```

I use my laptop (mainly) in three places. At home I use WPA and it works just fine. At work and the University they use WPA2 and it stays very unstable. It connects successfully but after a few minutes it drops. Only a new reconnection would bring it back online.

Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (or a similar related issue to yours) was reported on [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1865487&page=2).

The recommendation was to try the following workaround - this disables wireless-N support:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/options.conf
```

Copy and paste the following text:

```
options iwl4965 11n_disable=1
```

Save and reboot.

Comment: This tweak makes wireless usable, however, only barely. The output of `iwconfig` shows lots of dropped packets under `Invalid misc:`. Are there other options to try?

Comment: not sure - but a small bounty on this question will probably elicit another answer.  Remember, wireless issues are kernel specific - so if you are using 12.04 then this answer probably doesnt apply to you - the OP is using 11.10.  Thus a new Q would be appropriate.